# Program not able to find tensorflow.js model

Tags: javascript, python, http, tensorflow.js

Currently I am working on loading in a tensorflow model from either my github or through the webserver for Chrom extension.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js">
</script>
<script>

    async function tensorFlow(){
        
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://github.com/Heroice18/Your-Story/blob/devel/AI-Model/model.json');

    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://127.0.0.1:8887/model.json');    

}

tensorFlow();

</script>
```

[Localhost directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDJPu.png)

The problem is when I try to specify where the program should find the json file I get the following error for both methods.

```
http.js:149 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request to https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://127.0.0.1:8887/model.json failed with status code 404. Please verify this URL points to the model JSON of the model to load.
    at t.<anonymous> (http.js:149)
    at u (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:274)
    at Generator.forEach.t.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:97)
    at Wm (runtime.js:728)
    at o (runtime.js:728)
```

I have the cor-anywhere http added on to the URL as I wasn't able to load in my model without getting by CORS Policy.

Can someone explain to me why I can't load in this json model?

Comment: Does ```const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('https://github.com/Heroice18/Your-Story/blob/devel/AI-Model/model.json');``` work?

Comment: No it does not work @yudhiesh

Comment: Ok then could you just download the json file and add it to your project dir?

Comment: How would I do that @yudhiesh?

Comment: The only way I got things to play nice in Chrome Extension is to package into the Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think the url you used to get around CORS is not where the actual `.json` file is stored — go to `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://127.0.0.1:8887/model.json` and see if the json file is actually there. If there is, then your model should show up as text; otherwise you'll get a 404 not found.

You can keep looking around on your webserver for the model too, it may be located at `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/model.json` instead.

Alternatively, I usually get around the CORS by bundling my model .json and shards in a folder in the static resources, and loading it in by path from there.